# Convert dict list to dict set list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
graph = {'1': ['2', '21'],
         '2': ['3', '1'],
         '3': ['4', '2'],
         '4': ['5', '3'],
         '5': ['6', '4'],
         '6': ['12', '5'],
         '7': ['13', '8'],
         '8': ['7', '9'],
         '9': ['8', '10'],
         '10': ['9', '11']}
```

and I want output as

```
graph = {'1': set(['2', '21']),
         '2': set(['3', '1']),
         '3': set(['4', '2']),
         '4': set(['5', '3']),
         '5': set(['6', '4']),
         '6': set(['12', '5']),
         '7': set(['13', '8']),
         '8': set(['7', '9']),
         '9': set(['8', '10']),
         '10': set(['9', '11'])}
```

I am new to python and can't figure out a way. I have tried zip but it throws error of unhashable type list.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, if you want to get a proper answer you need to update your question with the code that you have tried so far and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i m sorry for my naive approach. will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for k,v in graph.items():
    graph[k] = set(v)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You just saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

You already have an answer how to modify your dictionary in place. If you need a new dictionary, you can use a comprehension.

```
{k:set(graph[k]) for k in graph}
```

or alternatively

```
{k:set(v) for k,v in graph.iteritems()}
```

Use the one which you think is easier to read. If you are using Python3, use `items` instead of `iteritems`.

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly.

Comment: @VIVEKSAH no problem